# Insert decimal with 3 decimal places

Tags: navision

I'm trying to insert a decimal number with 3 decimal places but I'm getting the error "Your entry of is not an acceptable value" error

This happens in my page in the purchase lines part.

In my table Purchase Lines the field "PVP" is a decimal.

[image]

Comment: How is anyone meant to answer this without knowing what code you have in your validation trigger, etc.?

Comment: I cant find any code to validate / test to PVP field, neither in the table or the page Purchase order

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by going to table "general ledger setup" and put 5 in the "decimal places number" and "decimal number" value to 2:3